# How to use Eclipse/PyDev's debugger with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Has anyone successfully been able to configure ArcGIS 10 to use PyDev's debugging server for debugging?  How do you set that up?  I have PyDev working fine by itself, with ArcPy working fine, but I can't bind the debugger to scripts I run from ArcToolbox.  I notice you can specify a debugger in ArcGIS, so I was wondering if it's possible to use the PyDev debug server.  Anyone have opinions/tips/guidance?

Comment: What happens when you specify PyDev as the debugger in the options window?

Comment: PyDev is just an extension to Eclipse, so I'm not sure how one would go about formatting the proper text to enter there.

Answer (score 2):

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html looks like it has instructions that will do the trick.

You'll have to make some additions to your python code itself, specifically:

- Make an addition to sys.path so it includes the path for pydevd.py from the Eclipse plugin (Alternatively, you could set the PYTHONPATH environment variable).
- Import the pydevd module and call pydevd.settrace().